# Mailchimp Outlook Conditional CSS not taking effect

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, mailchimp

Coding an email template through Mailchimp, and while I have got it working for every HTML based email client. Outlook's Microsoft Word based email client is having some trouble. I've followed [Mailchimp's documentation](https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/) but have had no luck with the code actually taking place. We're trying to target all Outlook mail clients & I'm currently testing on Outlook 365, which is also having the problem.

Here is some example of our code, **it is being placed at the end of the body.**

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
  .orange-block {margin: 0px !important;}
  .orange-block {width: 600px !important;}
  .orange-block {padding: 20px !important;}

  .orange-image {margin-left: 30px !important;}

  .templateImage {width: 600px !important;}
  .templateImage {margin: 0px !important;}
  .socialicon {height: 23px !important;}
  .socialicon {width: 23px !important;}
  .socialicon {margin: 10px !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

I've really tried to keep it simple & straightforward. But none of the code above takes place. Any idea why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't have enough rep to post a comment yet (otherwise I would ask you there) to posts an example of your HTML as well. So please do so if possible so we can have a working code snippet.

I have had some success with this by Adding your CSS above below the opening  tag of your HTML. This is a very broad question though as it is impossible to tell why your CSS will not render in a specific mail client without seeing the markup it is meant to select.

That being said I would suggest you try this

```css
<!--[if mso]>
<style type="text/css">
.class-name {
  color: red!important;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Paste it below the opening < body > tag and change .class-name to a value in your Markup.

I have spent a great deal of time learning how to cater for Outlook mail clients on Windows and would be happy to help if you could supply your HTML as well.

Also the 9 in your above snippet is not going to work in 365:

See this from the Mailchimp docs: https://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/outlook-conditional-css/

Outlook Version Numbers
Using Microsoft Office version numbers allows you to target specific Outlook clients. In the example above, ‘mso 9’ is Office 2000, which means you’re targeting Outlook 2000. Other version numbers allow you to target other clients, meaning you can build stylesheets tailored to each version of Outlook.

Outlook 2000 - Version 9
Outlook 2002 - Version 10
Outlook 2003 - Version 11
Outlook 2007 - Version 12
Outlook 2010 - Version 14
Outlook 2013 - Version 15

Comment: Hi mate, I tried yours out & it does indeed work. I have removed the 9 & 15 and have now been seeing some minor success! Thanks a ton! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
  .orange-block {margin: 0px !important;}
  .orange-block {width: 600px !important;}
  .orange-block {padding: 20px !important;}
  .orange-image {margin-left: 30px !important;}
  .templateImage {width: 600px !important;}
  .templateImage {margin: 0px !important;}
  .socialicon {height: 23px !important;}
  .socialicon {width: 23px !important;}
  .socialicon {margin: 10px !important;}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Outlook 2007-2019 ignores classes for image width, height, margin. Apply the values directly to the images:

```
<img src="" width="600" height="23" class="templateImage" />
```

You can use the classname to alter the image in modern email clients.

Outlook ignores `margin:`. Try `Margin:` instead.

Outlook 2013-2019 have spotty support for `padding`. You can apply a padding to a `<td style="padding: 20px;">` directly, but Outlook will ignore padding on images and other instances.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I also figured my entire email is sprawled with <div> which I believe Outlook is just completely ignoring any form of CSS. I think I'll need to re-do a lot of the HTML? Thoughts?

Comment: You can create great-looking emails in Outlook. It just takes a lot of effort. I generally avoid `<div>` because Outlook does not have full support. `<table>` works fine with Outlook and other email clients.